# Не удается получить данные из SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Решил переписать свое рабочее приложение с применением ряда библиотек (RX, Retrofit..., суть не в том). Реально убиваю второй вечер над куском кода, который раньше был рабочим.
Суть вопроса: мне нужно выбрать данные из таблицы EventTable с учетом равенства по значению COMPETITION_ID.

Создание таблицы:

```
public class FootballBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String NAME = "footballDataBase";

    public FootballBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                        .....
        db.execSQL("create table " + EventTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                EventTable.Cols.MATCH_ID + ", " +
                EventTable.Cols.COMPETITION_ID + ", " +
                  ...
                ")"
        );
    }
```

СХЕМА:

```
public class SchemaDB {
                    ...
        public static final class EventTable{
            public static final String NAME = "eventTable";
            public static final class Cols{
                public static final String MATCH_ID = "matchId";
                public static final String COMPETITION_ID = "competitionId";
                  ...
            }
        }
   }
```

метод в котором я обновляю или вношу записи в БД:

```
    public void updateAndInsertEvents(List<Event> eventsList) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDataBasemDataBase = new FootballBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();

    int competitionId = eventsList.get(0).getCompetitionId();
    Log.i(TAG, "COMPETITION_ID  = " + competitionId); // в логе выводит COMPETITION_ID  = 445

    String args = String.valueOf(competitionId);

    Cursor cursor = mDataBase.query(EventTable.NAME, null, EventTable.Cols.COMPETITION_ID + " =? ", new String[]{args}, null, null, null);

    Log.i(TAG, "CURSOR.getCOUNT() = " + cursor.getCount()); // выводит CURSOR.getCOUNT() = 0, хотя данные с таким COMPETITION_ID в таблице уже есть

    try {
         if (cursor.getCount() == 0) { 
// если курсор пуст, значит данных о таком чемпионате нет и производим вставку
             for (int i = 0; i < eventsList.size(); i++) {
                 long insertRorCount = mDataBase.insert(EventTable.NAME, null, getContentValuesOfEvent(eventsList.get(i)));
// описание метода getContentValuesOfEvent, ниже
          Log.i(TAG, "insert element in " + EventTable.NAME + "COMPETITION_ID = " + eventsList.get(i).getCompetitionId()); 
//выводит в лог, что вставка произведена и COMPETITION_ID  = 445
                    }
                }
                else {
                 // здесь данные должны обновляться если курсор не пуст...
                }
            }
            finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    private ContentValues getContentValuesOfEvent(Event event){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EventTable.Cols.MATCH_ID, event.getId());
        values.put(EventTable.Cols.COMPETITION_ID, event.getCompetitionId());
           ....
        return values;
    }
```

Часть логов я убрал из последнего метода, чтоб читалось лучше, но определенно каждый раз курсор после запроса пуст и раз за разом вставляю в базу одни и те же данные. Пробовал сносить приложение - не помогает.
Что то, наверное в самом условии, может, так как если запросить так

```
Cursor cursor = mDataBase.query(EventTable.NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

получаю курсор "набитый" повторяющимися данными

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение:

```
values.put(EventTable.Cols.COMPETITION_ID, String.valueOf(event.getCompetitionId()))`;
```

То есть в `POJO` классе `COMPETITION_ID` сохраняется целым числом и так же записывается в БД, а в параметры `DataBase.query()` нужно передавать строку, хотя здесь уже мне не понятно, как все же произвести выборку по `int`?